# eigenvalues of adjoint operator of a diagonizable complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{n}$. Define a linear $\operatorname{map} \operatorname{ad}(A): M_{n}(\mathbb{C}) \longrightarrow M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ by $\operatorname{ad}(A)(B)=A B-B A$ for $B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. Determine the eigenvalues of $\operatorname{ad}(A)$ in terms of $\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{n}$.

Here, we assume that $A$ is diagonizable.

Previously, I worked on the following question:

> Let $W$ be the subspace of $M_2(\mathbb R)$ consisting of $2 \times 2$ matrices with trace $0$. Let $V$ be the space of linear maps from $W$ to $W$. Define a linear map $T : W \rightarrow V$ by $A \mapsto \operatorname{ad}(A)$, where
> $\operatorname{ad}(A)(B) = AB - BA$ for $B \in W$. Choose bases for $W$ and $V$ and compute the matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases.

and solved it like this:

First, we introduce a base for $W$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{B}_W= \bigg \{ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\bigg \}.
\end{equation*}
Now, for $V$ we have the following set as a base with respect to $\mathcal{B}_W$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \mathcal{B}_V=\{T_{ij}:= &\text{The $3 \times 3$ matrix that the only nonzero element} \\  &\text{of it is the $ij$-th element, that equals $1$} \mid 1 \leq i, j \leq 3  \}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Now, to compute the matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases, first note that for any $1 \leq i \leq 3$, we have $\alpha_i . \alpha _i=0$. So, without loss of generality, writing the matrix $A$ as $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$, and $B=(a\alpha_1, b \alpha_2, c\alpha_3)$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    T\alpha_1 (a, b, c) &= (2c, 0, -b), \\
    T\alpha_2 (a, b, c) &= (0, -2c, a), \\
    T\alpha_3 (a, b, c) &= (-2a, 2b, 0).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Now, writing this in forms of matrices, we'll have:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    T\alpha_1&= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\\
    T\alpha_2&= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\\
    T\alpha_3&= \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So, the matrix of $T$ is going to be a $9 \times 3$ matrix as following:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 0 & -2\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 \\
    0 & -2 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

Now, I think to solve the eigenvalues question, I should be able to use the second question I mentioned, however I don't know how and where to start. any help's appreciated.

Comment: there is a result in invariant theory for matrices that may interest you: If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $G:=GL(V)$ is the general linear group on $V$ it follows there is the adjoint action of $G$ on $End_k(V)$: $\sigma(g,A):=gAg^{-1}$. The characteristic polynomial $det(tI-A):=p_A(t)$ has coefficients $s_i$ that are invariant under this action. They generate the invariantring $A^G$ where $A:=k[x_{i,j}], i,j\in \{1,..,n\}$.

Comment: there is a theorem called the "First fundamental theorem for $GL(V)$" - look up a book on "invariant theory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing two things. Your map $T$ takes $A$ to $\operatorname{ad}(A)$. That bears little relation to the eigenvalues of $\operatorname{ad}(A)$, which is what you are asking about.

And this is just a straight computation. The fact that $A$ is diagonalizable allows you to assume that $A$ is diagonal with diagonal $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Then
$$
(AB-BA)_{kj}=(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)B_{kj}.
$$
In coordinates, then, the eigenvalue equation $\operatorname{ad}(A)B=\alpha B$ looks
$$
(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)B_{kj}=\alpha\,B_{kj}. 
$$
So as soon as some $B_{kj}\ne0$, this forces $\alpha=\lambda_k-\lambda_j$. Choosing $B$ to be the matrix $E_{kj}$ that has $1$ in the $k,j$ entry and zeroes elsewhere, you get $\operatorname{ad}(A)B=(\lambda_k-\lambda_j) B$. Thus the eigenvalues of $\operatorname{ad}(A)$ are $$\big\{\lambda_k-\lambda_j:\ k,j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}\big\}.$$

Comment: I think you should have $\lambda_k-\lambda_j$ instead of their product.

Comment: Indeed, edited. Thanks.

Comment: Oh i got it! Thank you so much